# Burning DVD+R DL backup on OS X 10.8 via Disk Utility, .ISO too large?

Tags: macos, backup, dvd, osx-mountain-lion, iso-image

I have a DVD dual layer backup ISO file that, when uncompressing turned out to be 8.74 GB and has an associated .dvd file.

I am a bit confused as as the DVD+R DL files I have only have a capacity of 8.5 GB.

I've burned backups before (a long time ago), so I'm not sure if I was able to because they were smaller ISOs or something.

I'm unable to burn the backup ISO via Disk Utility because I'm getting errors that the file is too large.

Answer (score 0):

one way to deal with it I suppose is to find a 10.8 iso on a diet

the 10.8 iso I have is 4400029696 long:
shasum  ~/Downloads/*iso
7b16accec130155be2764e4be31745c41f488877  /Users/whatever/Downloads/10.8.iso

haven't used that one though (yet)